# Is it possible to generate 2 identical RSA ciphertext given the same plaintext and public key?

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, key-pair

I'm playing around with RSA on Android, and I realize that RSA encryption generates different ciphertext given the same plaintext and public key, due to padding Is there a way to generate the same ciphertext given the same plaintext and public key?

Similarly, do digital signatures differ between runs given the same plaintext and private key, and is there a way to generate the same digital signatures?

Here's my keygen:

```
        KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(ctx)
                    .setAlias(mAlias)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + mAlias))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1337))
                    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                    .build();
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(mAlias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .build();
        kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
        KeyPair kp = kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

Here's how I'm encrypting:

```
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(mAlias, null);
        Cipher cip = null;

        RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)entry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
        cip = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cip.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        byte[] encryptBytes = cip.doFinal(challenge.getBytes());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you're encrypting? The RSA algorithm *on its own* is deterministic, so given the exact same plaintext and public key, the encrypted output should not differ. If you're using Java's [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher), some of the modes (e.g. CBC) will start with a random IV if not otherwise specified.

Comment: Yes, you can request a cipher string without padding. But why do you want to do that?

Comment: How would I request a cipher string without padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate always the same cipher text use an algorithm with no padding. Replace `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` with `RSA/ECB/NoPadding`.

But, for security reasons, I suggest to use an algorithm with padding, and if possible OAEP `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding`(It is available from android 23). The padding should not be a problem for the decryption side

A PCKS#1 digital signature will produce the same result for the same private key and data to sign

Comment: Thanks! This works. Would you happen to know if key material is only accessible by the creating process/app? Also, is key material persistent (in both software KeyStore and hardware-backed KeyStore)? By that, I mean do the keys in the KeyStore get deleted after the creating app is uninstalled, and also upon a factory reset?

Comment: The key material is only accesible (but not extractable) by the application that has created it. The hardware support depends on the device, if available will be used (there is an api method to check if exists). If you uninstall the application or reset the device, then the keys will no longer be accessible.

Comment: Thanks. What about a rooted device? Would other apps or the root user be able to access the key material in this case? Also, does a factory reset really also wipe out key material that is hardware-backed (residing within the TEE)?

Comment: No, anyone can't extract the key material. Take a look here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#Security "Even the OS kernel cannot access this key material." I do not know if a hardware-reset will really delete the keys (probably yes), but they will be unusable as if you uninstall the app

Comment: Thanks again. That was helpful